# How to write pig script for calculating node degree and count

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How to write pig script for this ?

I have a text file that has ids of users who are friends with one another
for example (data.txt)

```
id  id
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   5
3   1
4   8
```

so user id 1 is friend with 3 people, user id 2 is friend with 2 people and so on...

I want to calculate and list in decreasing order the maximum number of friends and how many users have that many number of friends

So something like this: 1 user has 3 friends, 1 user has 2 friend, 2 users have 1 friend
trying to get list like this

```
number of user    number of friends (highest first)
1                   3
1                   2
2                   1
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: In the output why the user 1 is coming 2 times, 1- 3, 1-2? Is the output is like this 1-3,2-2,3-1,4-1?  Can you confirm?

Comment: In the output, 1 represents the number of user (not id). so in the dataset there is one user with id 1 who has 3 friends (with ids, 2,3,4), and there is another 1 user (with id 2) who has two friends (with ids, 1,5). so in other words, there is 1 user who has 3 friends, there is 1 user user who has 2 friends, and there are 2 users who have 1 friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input.txt**

```
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       5
3       1
4       8
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD  'input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS(id:int,friends:int);
B = GROUP A BY id;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(COUNT(A.friends)) AS cnt;
D = GROUP C BY cnt;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE COUNT(C.cnt),group;
F = ORDER E BY group DESC;
DUMP F;
```

Output:

```
(1,3)
(1,2)
(2,1)
```